# Server (Win2008) has correct time, but all workstations (Win7) are ahead one hour

Tags: networking, windows-8, date-time

Thanks for reading.

The network in question has one DC, which is a Windows 2008 R2 Server.  All workstations are Windows 7 Pro.

This last Monday (9/22) I noticed the time was suddenly ahead by an hour on all the workstations in my domain.  Not sure if it happened Monday or over the weekend.

I checked the server, and it was also off by an hour, so I updated the time on the server, and updated the time on the workstations.

Now the time is correct on the server, but the time on all the workstations keeps resetting to be an hour ahead.  I've restarted the time service on the server and workstations, rebooted the workstations (not the server yet, though I may be able to late tonight if necessary), and tried manually changing the time on the workstations.  I've also verified everything has the correct time zone, which is Pacific.

I don't know much about network time sync, but it seems like the server is pushing the wrong time or zone to the workstations even though it's using the correct time and zone for itself.  It also seems like to big a coincidence that this happened just before the first day of Fall.

Any ideas?

Comment: Verify time zones and day light savings settings are correct on the client machines.  If the clients are ahead one hour there is a logical reason caused by a configration

Answer (score 1):

Try the net time command. I'm on a mobile so I can't get links, but if you google NET TIME you will get the full syntax.

Comment: Good idea.  Tried it though - no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same time zones on both server and workstation? For example, I am in the UK (for which I would choose GMT). If my server said GMT but my workstation said Pacific (which I believe is 8 hours behind), the synced time would be 8 hours behind what the server reported.

Comment: They all have Pacific (UTC-08:00 Pacific Time (US & Canada)).